# ACCESS 2010 SQL No data returned. SQL Returns data same query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the same SQL query in Access and I checked it out in SQL Server and coming up with two different results.  In access I am getting 0 records sent back (Recordcount = 1) but nothing shows.  In SQL I get about 30 records.  Not sure what is going on.

```
Dim sql as String
Dim rs As Recordset
sql = "SELECT * FROM Client Where State = 'MN'"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
'Being called from frmClient
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUpdate2", acNormal
```

The text fields on frmUpdate2 are coming up blank.
Control Source is correct and matches

```
Filter Lookup = Database Default
Enabled = Yes
```

frmUpdate2:

```
Record Source = Client
Recordset Type = Dynaset
Allow Additions = Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another form property called *"Data Entry"* which may be involved.  (Find it on the *"Data"* tab of the form's property sheet.)

That property doesn't mean what many people expect.

With `Data Entry = Yes`, the form allows you to add new records but existing records are not displayed.

Ensure the property is set as `Data Entry = No` if you want to both display/edit existing records and add new records.